# PrimeNg p-dropdown custom filter

Tags: angular, primeng

I try to use my own custom filter field in p-dropdown element. I can see my input but it's not working. How to solve it?

I made it like this:

```
                        <p-dropdown
            [placeholder]="'common.select' | translate"
            [options]="possibleSelect"
            [virtualScroll]="possibleSelect?.length > 5"
            [itemSize]="10"
            [filter]="true"
            filterBy="label"
            optionLabel="label"
            optionValue="value"
            filterMatchMode="startsWith"
            id="BAdropdown"
            formControlName="Id"
            ariaLabelledBy="selectSr">
            <ng-template pTemplate="dropdownicon">
              <e-icon [type]="'primeNg'" [icon]="'expand_more_24'" [color]="'default-light-1'"></e-icon>
            </ng-template>          
            <ng-template pTemplate="filter">
               <div class="p-dropdown-filter-container ng-star-inserted">
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="p-dropdown-filter p-inputtext p-component" aria-owns="BAdropdown_list">
              </div>
            </ng-template>
          </p-dropdown>
```